# How can Sendmail reject email to a local user *unless* it comes from a trusted subnet?

Tags: email, sendmail, spam

I have sendmail set up to accept mail for a few domains and to relay messages for a few subnets' worth of systems.  Recently a particular internal-use-only address has been receiving a lot of spam.  I've been asked to simply drop any mail destined for this address unless the mail originated from one of the computers for which this system will relay mail.

I know I can do this with procmail, but I'd prefer to tie it into sendmail so that nonconforming email will be rejected outright at the MTA level.  I can't figure out how to get sendmail to do this (or whether it's even possible).

I have sendmail configured with the following settings:

```
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')`
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')
```

`/etc/mail/access` contains:

```
example.com              RELAY
connect:192.168.15       OK
to:internal@example.com  REJECT
```

And I'm generating `/etc/mail/access.db` via `makemap hash /etc/mail/access.db </etc/mail/access`.

When I try to use that configuration, however, even local machines get `550 5.2.1 <internal@example.com>... Mailbox disabled for this recipient` messages when trying to send to the internal address.

Can I configure sendmail to do what I want and, if so, how?

Comment: 1) Are you ready for medium level sendmail.cf "programming"? [a few lines] 2) Do you use anti-spam and anti-virus milter(s)?

Comment: I've only worked with the M4 sendmail.mc up to now, but I wouldn't be averse to sendmail.cf stuff (as long as it can be embedded in sendmail.mc).  We're using one milter: ClamAV.  Our anti-spam measures are DNSBLs and Spamassassin (which is called from our LDA).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I dont want to offend you, but is this the exact content of your /etc/mail/access.db?

```
example.com              RELAY    
connect:192.168.15       OK    
to:internal@example.com  REJECT
```

Cause it should be a hash map. The above should be the content of your /etc/mail/access.
Then compile it to a map:
makemap hash /etc/mail/access.db < /etc/mail/access

Comment: Sorry; I thought saying "source file" would be clear enough.  What I quoted is in `/etc/mail/access`, which is processed into `/etc/mail/access.db` via `makemap hash /etc/mail/access.db < /etc/mail/access`.  I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Oh. My bad. Sorry.

Comment: Is there a way that works?